# Convert curl to Pycurl.

Tags: python, curl

I have this curl command and I would like to know if I have converted it   correctly to pycurl.

curl command

```
curl -D- -u fred:fred -X PUT --data{see below} -H "Content-Type:application/json" http://kelpie9:8081/rest/api/2/issue/QA-31

{
 "fields":
{
"assignee":{"name":"harry"}
}
}
```

python code

```
def assign(self, key, name):
data = json.dumps({"fields":{"assignee":{"name":name}}}) 
c= pycurl.Curl()
c.setopt(pycurl.VERBOSE, 1)
c.setopt(pycurl.URL, "http://xxx/rest/api/2/issue/"+ key )
c.setopt(pycurl.HTTPHEADER, ['Content-Type: application/json', 'Accept: application/json'])
c.setopt(pycurl.USERPWD, "****") 
c.setopt(pycurl.PUT, 1) 
c.setopt(pycurl.POSTFIELDS,data)
c.perform(
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nopes. First off: use curl's [--libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#--libcurl) option to get a first template.

Then, "-X PUT" translates to [CUSTOMREQUEST](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST.html) set to "PUT", only changing the actual method keyword.

Comment: Hello Daniel. I understand what you mean but I am finding it difficult to get the template using libcurl. I am relatively new to pycurl. Can you please give me a more detailed explanation please. Thank you for helping me out.

Comment: Use the template mostly to get the set of option names and the arguments since the output syntax isn't completely pycurl.

Answer (score 0):

I would personally accomplish this by using the remarkable [requests](http://www.python-requests.org) library

```
import requests
import requests.auth
import json


def assign(key, name):
    url = "http://xxx/rest/api/2/issue/" + key
    headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'application/json'}
    data = json.dumps({"fields": {"assignee": {"name": name}}})

    r = requests.put(url, data=data, headers=headers, auth=requests.auth.HTTPBasicAuth('fred', 'fred'))

    print(r.status_code)
    print(r.json())
```

Comment: I have to follow many restrictions regarding import and "import requests" is not supported. Is there any other way to do this using only pycurl and json.

Answer (score 0):

```
curl -j --libcurl git.txt -D- -u fred:fred -X PUT --data"{\"fields\":{\"assignee\":{\"name\":\"FRED\"}}}" -H "Content-Type:application/json" http://kelpie9:8081/rest/api/2/issue/QA-31
```

this gives the template in git.txt .

Also in the data field the inner quotes must be escaped as shown above.

The working code is attached below.

```
   def assign(self, key, name):
    self._startCurl()         
    self.c.setopt(pycurl.URL, "http://xxx/rest/api/2/issue/"+ key )
    self.c.setopt(pycurl.HTTPHEADER, ['Content-Type: application/json', 'Accept: application/json'])
    self.c.setopt(pycurl.USERPWD, "fred:fred") 
    self.c.setopt(pycurl.CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT")
    data = json.dumps({"fields":{"assignee":{"name":name}}})
    self.c.setopt(pycurl.POSTFIELDS,data)        
    self.c.perform()
    self.c.close()
```

Thanks to Daniel Stenberg for pointing it out